# How can I add keys in the array, and generate input fields with them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The user has the possibility to enter his name. I get the name in a array. Example: `["Dilan", "Chris", "Robert"]`

So what I'm trying to do is to get the name from the user, but also another value inside the array.
Example:

```
initialName = {
  name: "",
  active: "",
};
```

Also, I need the `initalName` to be inside an array.

This is what I have tried by far

```
const initialName = {
  name: "",
  active: ""
};

export default function AddingNames() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([initialName ]);

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setLanguages([...names, initialName]);
  };
  
  const handleItemChanged = (event, index) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const list = [...initialName];

    list[index] = value;
    setNames(list);
    console.log(names);
  };
```

And this error is showed: `TypeError initialName is not iterable`

What I want to get from the user its just the name value in the initialName.
How can I make it work?

Comment: `[{...initialArray}]`?

Comment: You cannot use the spread operator on an object inside of an array. It should be another array if you want to spread.

Comment: Should this `const list = [...initialName];` be `const list = [...names];`?

Answer (score 0):

So initial name is not iterable here as you are trying to do in usestate([]) because initial name is an object not an array. If you had an array say:

```js
let users = [{
     name: "",
     active: "",
}]
```

Then you could iterate over the users array and access the name of a user by

```js
let variable = user[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only use `...` in case of iterable variable, in this case initialName is not iterable since its object

I suppose you are trying to achieve array that looks something like this:

```
    list = 
    [
      {name: "boo", active: "foo"},
      {name: "john", active: "doe"}
    ]
```

In this case what you could do is

```
list[index] = {name: value, active: ""};
setNames(list)
```

Comment: Tried your logic, but when I add a second input field(which means another item on the array) it shows this error: ```Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')```

Comment: please see the edit, my mistake